# Element with background color vertical align middle of the parent

Tags: javascript, html, css, alignment

I am trying to achieve this "stupid" thing, but I can't find a solution.
I have a certain number of images one above the other, I would try to put background-color which is aligned vertically in the middle of the first and last image.
more difficult to explain than to understand, I made an image explanatory so I think it is more easy to understand [image]

I tried to make a codepen, but without success http://codepen.io/mp1985/pen/BoEMPN

```
.bg {
  background: red;
  top: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  bottom:0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  backgrund-position: center center;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

do you have any advice or suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure I've understood but how you started isn't correct: you want your images at the center of the page, right? Well, to do that they must be positionated with

```
position: relative;
left:50%;
```

Then, you created a div as a background. There you can choose: you can create a dinamic background with JS, or add only a certain number of images with a certain known height. I guess you are creating a static page, so set the div with

```
position: relative;
min-height: 900px; //(imgNum-1)*imgHeight 
top: 150px; //imgHeight/2
```

and with what you have already set.
If you have width problems, min-width and max-width are useful attributes.

In my mind it works. Please comment for issues and rate positive if useful

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the parent's height according to an absolutely positioned element. So you have to use fixed lengths rather than percentages.

```
.container {
  height: 900px; // img-height * 4
}
```

Then, for the background color to align to the center of the first image, add this:

```
.bg {
  top: 150px; // img-height / 2
}
```

As for horizontally centering the imgs, use

```
.box-images {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -300px; // img-width / 2
}
```